# How to generate a 3-layer empty list in R? I want list, not array. Thanks a lot

Tags: r, list

I want to generate a 3-layer **empty** list L in R, Thank you very much for your help:

the 3 dimensions are for example:

`length (L) = 3`
`length (L[[1]]) = 4`
`length(L[[1]][[1]]) = 38`

The structure is like this:

`L[[1]]`

[image]

Comment: Do you want a list or an array? Lists can handle objects of different types, while arrays must contain objects of the same type.

Comment: see `?array`. I think this should work: myArray <- array(0, dim=c(3,4,38)). You can reorder the dimensions so that they make sense to what you want to do.

Comment: edit question and clarify what you are looking for, if you are not sure, then close question, read more about that, then ask new question when you will know more precisely what you need

Comment: @ lmo, Thank you very much. But it is still not what i need. i want exactly the same structure as in the picture.  @jangorecki, thank you for your suggestions

Comment: list of lists of numeric vectors, lapply's will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
replicate(3, replicate(4, numeric(38), simplify = FALSE), simplify=FALSE)
```

But there may be a simpler solution.